# How do include functiont using Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

i have a problem when include a view in laravel 5.4 
this is the error:

> 3/3) ErrorException Undefined variable: categories (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\partials\index.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\partials\index.blade.php)

my index:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@include('partials.index')


@endsection
________
// this is index in partials
<div class="container index-cat">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h1>Категория:</h1>
            <div class="pull-right add-cat">
                <a href="{{url('categories/create')}}" class="btn btn-success">Дабавить Катигорию</a>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                @foreach($categories as $cat)
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{asset ('storage/' . $cat->photo)}}" alt="...">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>{{$cat->title}}</h3>
                                <form action="{{url('categories/' . $cat->id)}}" method="POST">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                                    <div class="buttons-bootstrap">
                                        <a href="{{url('categories/' . $cat->id . '/description')}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">подробности</a>
                                        <a href="{{url('categories/' . $cat->id . '/edit')}}" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">редактировать</a>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">удалить</button>

                                    </div>

                                </form>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

**this is my controller**

```
  <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;


    use App\Http\Requests\catRequest;

    use App\Category;
    use App\User;
    use Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;




    class CategoryController extends Controller
    {
        //middleware auth
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');

        }
        public function show($id )
        {

            $cat = Category::query()->find($id);




            return view('categories.description' , ['categories' => $cat]);
        }

        public function index(){
           //$listCat = Category::all();

           $listCat = Category::where('user_id' , Auth::user()->id)->get();
            return view('categories.index' , ['categories' => $listCat]);
        }
        public function create(){
            return view('categories.create');
        }
        public function store( catRequest $request  ){


             //return $request->all();
            $cat = new Category();
            $cat->title = $request->input('title');
            $cat->description = $request->input('description');
            $cat->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            if($request->hasFile('photo')){
                $cat->photo = $request->photo->store('photo');
            }
            $cat->save();
            session()->flash('success' , 'Катигория дабавлена');
            return redirect('categories');

        }

        /**
         * @param $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
         */
        public function edit($id){

            $cat = Category::query()->find($id);


            return view('categories.edit' , ['categories' => $cat]);
        }

        /**
         * @param Request $request
         * @param $id
         */
        public function update(catRequest $request, $id){
            $cat = Category::query()->find($id);
            $cat->title = $request->input('title');
            $cat->description = $request->input('description');
            if($request->hasFile('photo')){
                $cat->photo = $request->photo->store('photo');
            }
            $cat->save();
            return redirect('categories');
        }
        public function destroy(Request $request, $id){
            $cat = Category::query()->find($id);
            $cat->delete();
            return redirect('categories');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code? It seems from the outset that you arent passing a variable to your view called `categories`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your error is describing a missing variable

> ErrorException Undefined variable: categories.

This means that the blade template can't see the `$categories` variable that you are using in the for loop.

Check your `web.php` or `app/Http/Controller/file.php` where the blade template is being called and be sure you are passing a variable along to the view function.

*example*

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']); // <= passing a variable $name with string 'James'
```

[Laravel Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)